# Can not wire from thread in Spring MVC

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I've got the service and it's implementation annotated with `@Service`. It works well in one-threaded app, but now I should do some logic from another thread using this service. This is my code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import ru.tenet.smsc.form.MassSMSForm;
import ru.tenet.smsc.service.SaveBatchService;


public class MassSmsRunnable implements Runnable {

    private MassSMSForm massSMSForm;

    private String userName;

    @Autowired
    SaveBatchService saveBatchService;

    public MassSmsRunnable(MassSMSForm massSMSForm, String userName) {
        this.massSMSForm = massSMSForm;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {         

        saveBatchService.sendMass(massSMSForm, userName); //here it is
        saveBatchService.save();
    }

}
```

But `NullPointerException` is all that I've got:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.tenet.smsc.thread.MassSmsRunnable.run(MassSmsRunnable.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: saveBatchService supports transactions?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Component
 public class MassSmsRunnable implements Runnable
```

And whereever you are using the runnable

```
@Inject
private MassSmsRunnable massSmsRunnable;
```

In MassSmsRunnable you need to inject massSMSForm and username in similar manner.

Comment: But my running code looks like this: Thread t=new Thread(new MassSMSRunnable()); Can I inject it the way you post?

Comment: with this you just instantiated MassSMSRunnable, you need to also inject the dependencies massSMSForm and username